# Library class (from Android sdk) depends on program class (again, Android sdk)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard, gradle-plugin

We are migrating from Android Gradle plugin 2.3.3 to Gradle plugin 3.0.1. Our application consists of an Application module and a Library module. Several dependencies are transitive (connected using `api` keyword) but even making them non-transitive using `implementation` doesn't help. After changing all the `compile`-type dependencies to the new ones, debug build works well. However, release build with Proguard shows thousands of warnings (on 2.3.3 everything goes well)

In particular, I don't get why do we have such problems, when Android classes from library depend on Android classes from program (here are just few examples):

```
Warning: library class android.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams extends or implements program class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
Warning: library class android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
```

Overall, there are next types of warnings that do not appear on Gradle plugin 2.3.3 (so, Proguard is already configured):

```
Warning: there were 72 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 1373 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: there were 1056 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is the list of dependencies (`gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration developmentDebugRuntimeClasspath` ):

```
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Configuration 'debugCompile' in project ':vyng-core' is deprecated. Use 'debugImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':vyng-core' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

developmentDebugRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: developmentDebug
+--- io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:1.3.4
|    \--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java:1.3.4
|         +--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java-api:1.3.4
|         +--- org.greenrobot:essentials:3.0.0-RC1
|         +--- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.7.2
|         \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4
|    \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-analyzer:1.5.4
|         +--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-watcher:1.5.4
|         \--- com.squareup.haha:haha:2.0.3
+--- project :vyng-core
|    +--- com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3
|    |    |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3
|    |    |    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2
|    |         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1
|    |    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.8.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0 -> 27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.1
|    |    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5
|    +--- com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:1.0.9
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8
|    +--- jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1
|    |    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0
|    |         +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.0.0
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |         +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.0.0
|    |         \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.0.0
|    +--- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.8.1
|    +--- com.bluelinelabs:conductor:2.1.3 -> 2.1.4
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6
|    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.1
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1 -> 2.1.6 (*)
|    +--- com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.5
|    |    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.17
|    |    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13
|    |    |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
|    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6
|    |    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
|    |    \--- com.github.tony19:apktool-lib:1.4.4-3
|    |         \--- com.google.android:android:2.1_r1
|    |              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|    |              |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|    |              |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |              |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|    |              +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|    |              +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|    |              \--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.4 -> r2.5.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0 -> 27.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.4 -> r2.5.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0 -> 27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0
|    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.2
|    |         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.2
|    |         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.8.0
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0
|    |         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.8.0
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.8.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.8.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.8.0
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.8.1
|    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7 -> 2.8.2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0 -> 2.1.6 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*)
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*)
+--- com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7
+--- com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:1.0.9 (*)
+--- com.github.jarrodholliday:material-about-library:1.8.4
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.0.2
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2 -> 1.1.0-beta4
|         \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0-beta4
+--- com.vdurmont:emoji-java:3.2.0
+--- eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc2
+--- com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4 (*)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6 (*)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1 (*)
+--- com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4
+--- oxim.digital:rx2anim:0.9.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.0.2
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2 -> 2.1.6 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0 -> 2.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1 -> 27.0.2
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
+--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.8.1
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2
+--- com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.2
|    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
|    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0 (*)
+--- jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-license:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0 (*)
+--- com.bluelinelabs:conductor:2.1.4 (*)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.24.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.5.1
|    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0 -> 27.0.2
+--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.5.1 (*)
+--- com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4
+--- com.github.jarrodholliday:videocache:2.7.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1 (*)
\--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Fix:**
I had this problem when upgrading to Gradle plugin 3.0.0, a quick solution is to add this in your proguard file,

```
-dontwarn android.**
```

This should work with 3.0.1 as well.

**Recommended:**
This occurs when you are using a library which is not referencing android class from support library or is referencing deprecated classes. My guess is,

```
com.github.tony19:logback-android-core
```

which you are using is causing this, you can remove this  dependency and try rebuilding. If this doesn't help you can try removing any other libraries that you are using but they aren't updated recently.

Comment: Strange. I tried -dontwarn android.** a little earlier but the program crashed on start. And now it works. Will try better solution later, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
-dontwarn android.**
```

**Won't solve your problem**. You need to look at the dependencies tree and find library that causes the problem.

For example in my case it was

```
+--- com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3
|    \--- com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|         |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|         +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|         +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|         +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|         \--- org.json:json:20080701
```

So you need to exclude com.google.android for this library

```
implementation ('com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
```